# XMPP facebook chat persmissions with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, api, xmpp

Using the Facebook Chat API, is it possible for a facebook "page", or the admins of a page, to send chat messages to people that have liked the page? Or must the receiver also have given permissions to accept XMPP messages?

Answer (score 0):

you can send chat message from your app to users but you cant send message directly.there is no need to give permission from friend of authorized person.then if i authorized to your app then you can send message through your app page to all of my chat's friends.

Comment: i own a facebook page. i created an app that i personally have given permissions to. can i send messages using the chat api from me or my page to the people that have liked my page?

Answer (score -1):

You can see how RumbleTalk have implemented the send chat messages to user facebook page.

Comment: This would be more suited to a comment as it doesn't really provide an answer